# Converting from JsError to Exception

Tags: scala, playframework, exception

I have a validate function that checks incoming JSON against a model schema. I currently have it set up as a `match` with `case err@jsError(_)`. That case maps into messages displaying the errors. This is all done in 1 controller method.

I would like to export this mapping of error messages to an exception handler but can't seem to convert or move the `JsError` over to an exception.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `.get` on a JsError, `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. The question is asking for a way to create an exception that conveys why the JS error occurred. Calling .get on a JsError will lead to a new and entirely unrelated exception. Here, the NoSuchElementException simply indicates that the JsError, which inherits from JsResult does not actually contain any value in it. This is similar to calling .get on None.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked a long time ago, but since I frequently have to solve the same problem in my application, I think it might be useful to share my solution.

The first thing to keep in mind is that a `JsError` is not an `Exception`. Rather, the superclass of `JsError` is `JsResult`. In the Scala Play framework, the output of a JSON parsing operation is a `JsResult`. This result is either successful, in which case its concrete manifestation will be `JsSuccess`, or a failure, in which case its concrete manifestation will be `JsError`. This is equivalent to how `Option`, `Some`, and `None` work. Calling `.get` on a `JsSuccess` will give you the parsed json object. On the other hand, since the json object has not been successfully parsed in the case of `JsError`, calling `.get` will result in `NoSuchElementException`.

Now that we know what `JsError` is and what it's for, here's one way you can generate a meaningful `Exception` from a `JsError`:

```
def handleResult[T](result: JsResult[T])(implicit rds: Reads[T]): T =
  result match {
    case success: JsSuccess[T] => success.get
    case failure: JsError => throw JsResult.Exception(failure)
  }
```

As you can see, you can use a `JsError` to initialize a `JsResult.Exception`, which is a case class that inherits from `Exception`. Under the hood, all that the `JsResult.Exception` constructor does is converting the `JsError`'s underlying JSON object containing the error message into a string and then using that string to create a new `Exception`:

```
case class Exception(cause: JsError)
  extends java.lang.Exception(Json.stringify(JsError.toJson(cause)))
  with scala.util.control.NoStackTrace
```